# Solaris-Mean of value in 'ls -lE'

Tags: shell, solaris, solaris-10

When doing the `ls -lE` command on Solaris, what is the meaning of the field that comes after the timestamp.

[image: ls -lE]

I've been looking on `man ls` but I only found something about the `POSIX Locale` related to `de -E` option.

Does anyone know what the `-0600`stands for? I'm guessing it could be something like -6 hours from the CST. Is that correct?

Comment: Why would it be -6 from Central Standard Time?   It is much more likely that it is -6 from UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)

Comment: Sorry, that right. Here I am (UTC-06:00)

Comment: If you're intending to parse the output of `ls`, don't: there are better ways to collect that information. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I appreciate you observation, as a point to consider. Luckly, in this case, I'm quering for a very specific pattern on a controlled environment, so I guess I'm be fine with the `ls | awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! It is offset from UTC(Coordinated Universal Time)

See following page.
http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/ls/